# How to open UI of JSP pages in browser?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a project which is made using JSP pages .
I need to open that project in my local server to do UI changes and test them.
Is there any way I can open that JSP pages in browser.

Comment: ehm ... yes. deploy it on your local server and go to the correct url

Comment: Can u explain how to deploy . I am quite new to JSP pages.

Comment: Install Tomcat server and copy all your JSP files to webapps folder. Start and access the page by accessing `http://IP:PORT/jspfilename`

Comment: What is a JSP, how to create and run it? See [Oracle Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagy.html) and [JSP at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy entire project to local machine and deploy in your local web server e.g. Apache Tomcat, now try to run the web server to open UI of the project using http://IP:PORT/jspfilename

You can make changes using notepad++ for editing the content.

Hope this is fine for you.